# How to use enum (attached to a class as a static variable) as a type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

```js
// file1.ts

enum Variant {
  Success = 'success',
  Error = 'error',
}

export class Example {
  static Variant = Variant;
}


// file2.ts

import { Example } from './file1';

type Props = {
  variant: Example.Variant; // TS2702: 'Example' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.
};
```

Typescript throws an error: `TS2702: 'Example' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.`

I know I can export the enum itself and use it in `file2.ts`, but I would like to know why the above example is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variant is a `static` class field

```js
export class Example {
  // Variant here is a class field
  static Variant = Variant;
}
```

So if you want to use Variant as a `type` through `class` `Example`, you should add `typeof` before `Example.Variant`

```js
import { Example } from './file1';

type Props = {
  // This statement means that Example is a namespace that contains Variant as a type or class named Variant, which in our case it is a field
  variant: Example.Variant; // wrong
  variant: typeof Example.Variant; // correct
};
```

So the error came because you're using `class` as a `namespace`

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)